# useState no me deja ingresar 2 caracteres iguales

Tags: reactjs, usestate

Tengo un input trabajando con useState y el evento onChange. Al apretar agregar texto, visualizo con la extensión  "React Developer Tools" como se agrega a mi arreglo.
El problema surge cuando ingreso un único carácter, por ejemplo "w", me lo ingresa correctamente, pero si vuelvo a colocar "w" no aparece y no genera ningún cambio. Esto solo ocurre cuando ingreso un carácter y luego quiero volver a ingresar el mismo. ¿ A que se debe ?

Coloque un reset en el input y también limpio el State pero aun sigue el problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta imagen ingrese el caracter "f" aparecio en el primer State, aprete "Agregar" y se agrego al segundo State y se limpiaron los datos.
Nuevamente volvi a colocar "f" y no aparece, y al apretar "Agregar" en consola me devuelve el mensaje de campo vacio, pero si coloco cualquier otro caracter, si lo reconoce y lo agrega.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const FormularioLista = () => {
  const [tarea, setTarea] = useState(" ");
  const [lista, setlista] = useState([]);

  const enviarDatos = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Verifica que no este vacio
    if (!tarea.trim()) {
      console.log("No se ha ingresado nada");
      return;
    }

    //Agrega la tarea al arreglo
    setlista([...lista, { id: "x", nombreTarea: tarea }]);

    //Limpia el campo y useState
    e.target.reset();
    setTarea("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="text-center mb-4">Crud Simple</h1>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-5 border">
            <h4 className="text-center">Agregar Tarea</h4>

            <form onSubmit={enviarDatos}>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control mt-3 mb-2"
                placeholder="Ingrese Tarea"
                onChange={(e) => setTarea(e.target.value)}
              />
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary ">
                Agregar
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default FormularioLista;
```

Comment: Tu problema se debe a la forma de trabajar que tiene el `e.target.reset()`. Por alguna razón que desconozco, esta función te limpia el input pero evita que se ejecute el evento `onChange` al ingresar el primer carácter luego del reinicio. Lo que hace que al tocar el botón "Agregar", por consola te diga que no ingresaste datos porque nunca se ejecutó dicho evento, y entonces el estado `tarea` continua vacío. Por lo tanto, yo también pienso que lo mejor es hacerlo de la manera que te recomienda @maxpsz .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En primer lugar, creo que te va a resultar mucho más sencillo utilizar el input como componente **controlado**.

Te dejo tu código con un par de cambios que creo que solucionan tu inconveniente:

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

const FormularioLista = () => {
  const [tarea, setTarea] = useState("");
  const [lista, setlista] = useState([]);

  const enviarDatos = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    //Verifica que no este vacio
    if (!nombreTarea.trim()) {
      console.log("No se ha ingresado nada");
      return;
    }

    const nombreTarea = tarea;

    //Agrega la tarea al arreglo
    setlista([...lista, { id: "x", nombreTarea }]);

    //Limpia el campo y useState
    setTarea("");
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <h1 className="text-center mb-4">Crud Simple</h1>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-5 border">
            <h4 className="text-center">Agregar Tarea</h4>

            <form onSubmit={enviarDatos}>
              <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control mt-3 mb-2"
                placeholder="Ingrese Tarea"
                value={tarea}
                onChange={(e) => setTarea(e.target.value)}
              />
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary ">
                Agregar
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default FormularioLista;
```

En caso de que los cambios no salten a simple vista, te cuento:

Agregué **value={tarea}** en el input, de manera que el contenido del input siempre sea igual al estado **tarea**, de esta forma evitas tener que estar reseteando el input, solo lo haces con el estado.

Por otra parte, antes de agregar la tarea a la lista, genero una nueva constante `const nombreTarea = tarea`, esto es para asegurarnos que dicha constante tiene el valor deseado de la tarea que vamos a agregar, ya que de la manera que React maneja internamente sus cambios de estado, no es siempre necesariamente síncrona, y esto puede llevar a errores involuntarios.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

es porque estas iniciando tu state como vacio `const [tarea, setTarea] = useState(" ");` y despues tomas el valor anterior y el nuevo valor, y como tu input no tiene ningun valor `(value)`, te crea un objecto desconocido y te agrega los datos que agregas en el input

```
setlista([...lista, { id: "x", nombreTarea: tarea }]);
```

en este caso es mejor crear un state con tus valores que deseas agregar, el id, lo veo un poco inecesario, pero como lo declaras como `x` por default, es igual que iniciarlo desde el inicio del state

```
const [tarea, setTarea] = useState({
        id: 'x',
        nombreTarea: ''
    });
```

resolviendo tu problema, quedaria de esta manera y si deseas limpiar el input al hacer el submit, solo llamas el state y declaras los datos vacios

```
setTarea({ id: 'x', nombreTarea: '' });


import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
const FormularioLista = () => {
    const [tarea, setTarea] = useState({
        id: 'x',
        nombreTarea: ''
    });
    const [lista, setlista] = useState([]);

    const enviarDatos = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('tareas', tarea);

        //Verifica que no este vacio
        if (!tarea?.nombreTarea.trim()) {
            console.log("No se ha ingresado nada");
            return;
        }
        // //Agrega la tarea al arreglo
        setlista(tarea);
        
        //si deseas limpiar el input al hacer el onclick
        setTarea({ id: 'x', nombreTarea: '' });

    };

    const handleChange = e => {
        setTarea({
            ...tarea,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    }

    console.log('tareas', tarea);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="container">
                <h1 className="text-center mb-4">Crud Simple</h1>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-5 border">
                        <h4 className="text-center">Agregar Tarea</h4>

                        <form onSubmit={enviarDatos}>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                className="form-control mt-3 mb-2"
                                name="nombreTarea"
                                value={tarea.nombreTarea}
                                placeholder="Ingrese Tarea"
                                onChange={handleChange}
                            />
                            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary ">
                                Agregar
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>

    );
}

export default FormularioLista;
```